# PHP remember me, COOKIE

Tags: php

I don't know where went wrong.
When I tick the remember me checkbox
The page didn't go to userarea page and seems like cookie didn't work as well
It works when I just login without tick the remember me checkbox

```
<?PHP
session_start();

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);


function loggedin(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    $loggedin=TRUE;
    return $loggedin;   
    }
}

if(loggedin()){
header("Location:userarea.php");}

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$rememberme=$_POST['rememberme'];

    if($email && $password){
        $login=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($login)){
            $db_email=$row['email'];
            $db_password=$row['password'];
            $db_firstname=$row['firstname'];
            $db_lastname=$row['lastname'];  

            if($password==$db_password){$log=TRUE;}
            else{$log=FALSE;}               
            }

            if($log==TRUE){
                if($rememberme=="on"){
                    setcookie("email", $email, time()+7200);
                }
                else if($rememberme==""){
                    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
                    header("Location:userarea.php");
                }
            }
            else{die("Wrong email or password");}
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="email" /><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password"/><br/>

        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme"> Remember me | <a href="register.php">Register?</a><br/>
         <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
     </form>
</html>
```

Comment: I also got an error when user didn't fill anything into text area
Undefined index: $rememberme
anyway to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong cookie variable name in the function loggedin(). Its should be isset($_COOKIE['email'])

```
function loggedin(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['email'])){
       $loggedin=TRUE;
       return $loggedin;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please vote it as a useful answer so that I can get some points. :)

Comment: I also got an error when user didn't fill anything into text area
Undefined index: $rememberme
anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Please check my second answer which will help you to fix the error :)

Answer (score 0):

Change like the following

```
if(isset($_POST['rememberme'])){
    $rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];
}
```

Then

```
if($log==TRUE){
    if(isset($rememberme)){
        setcookie("email", $email, time()+7200);
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['email']=$email;  
    }
    header("Location:userarea.php");
    exit();
}
```